# Does Khinchin's constant have an analog for nested radicals?

Tags: real-analysis, ergodic-theory, continued-fractions, nested-radicals, iterated-function-system

**Edit:** as multiple users have pointed out, the premise of my question assumes some canonical representation of real numbers as infinite nested radicals. There does not seem to be any such representation.

[Khinchin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant) is the peculiar number $K$ such that for *almost* any real number $x$, if we write out $x$'s continued fraction representation
$$x = a_0+\frac1{a_1+\frac1{\ddots}}$$
Then we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n} = K$$
My question begins with the fact that any real number $x$ may be written as
$$x = b_0+\sqrt{b_1 + \sqrt{b_2+\dots}}$$
And, given the similarity between continued fractions and nested radicals as iterated function systems/contractions, I would think there must be some number $S$ and non-trivial function $f$ such that for almost all $x$ we have
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}f(b_0,b_1 \dots b_n) = S$$
Where $f$ is probably defined independent of $b_0$.

*I nervously tag this post [ergodic-theory](/questions/tagged/ergodic-theory) because I know Khinchin relied on it in the proof for his constant.*

Comment: Given a positive irrational $x$, the sequence $(a_0, a_1, ...)$ giving the contiue fraction representation exists and is unique. How do you define, in general, the seuqnce $(b_0, b_1, ...)$? Does it exist and is it unique?

Comment: Similar to D. Thomine's point, there is a *canonical* continued fraction, which associates each real $x$ with a unique continued fraction. You would need to canonically define the nested radical.

Comment: You'd need to be careful about how you do it because $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\ldots}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{0+\ldots}}}}$ and so on. So the nested radicals, $(1,1,\bar{0}),\ (1,0,1,\bar{0}),\ldots$ all non-uniquely specify the same value.